# Speeding Up PHP page using Google Analytics Api

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I have a reporting tool for google analytics data found at:

http://arudd.bluehoststaff.com/reporting

I want to use is to be able to display multiple campaign data metrics that they care about quickly and easily for clients.  The problem is it takes forever to load each time I submit the request.  Is there a way to speed it up as it is?  Or is there a better way like downloading the data via a cron job into a database and then calling it?

Comment: Without you telling us about what tool this is and how it works, how do you expect us to give you advice on how to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not a solution but an explanation. Google Analytics API has two flavours: "normal" reporting API and Adhoc Reports (which are new).

The Reporting API interface lets you define a report and then poll for it's execution. You'll never get that on demand or request. Your proggy will be in a busy-wait-loop polling for the report to get ready for downloading. That may take it's time and is up to GA - and even times out with no result.

Due to that, Google has introduced the "Adhoc Reporting" which I'm not familiar with, since we are doing quite the same by downloading aggregated data in to a database by cron.

Comment: Have you found using a database and a cron allows for stability and scaleabity if for an example a client has over 100 profiles on a single account?

Comment: Actually, it's the only way to guarantee that - having a batch process retrieveing data for those accounts one after each other and aggregate that in to a database